# Using CONTAINS on view in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I have defined a full-text index on a table, so the following query works just fine:

```sql
SELECT Field FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(Field, 'text')
```

Also, there is a *legacy* view over the table, as follows:

```sql
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT * FROM MyTable
```

Is it possible to run the query against the view, not recreating it as indexed?

```sql
SELECT Field FROM MyView WHERE CONTAINS(Field, 'text')
```

I am getting `Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'MyView' because it is not full-text indexed`, which seems odd to me, as this defeats the view's purpose of query abstraction and is not the way regular indices work either.

Answer (score 0):

Creates a full-text index on a table or indexed view in a database in SQL Server. Only one full-text index is allowed per table or indexed view, and each full-text index applies to a single table or indexed view.

below link will be helpful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql

Comment: You missed the point. I did create the FTI on a table, however the issue is that it does not apply when I query a view over that table.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT * FROM MyTable

SELECT Field FROM MyView WHERE CONTAINS(Field, 'text')
```

Means :

```
SELECT Field FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable) WHERE CONTAINS(Field, 'text')
```

"SELECT * FROM MyTable" will be evaluated first and used WITHOUT any index with the main request... It can't work "as is".

You should consider to use a stored procedure returning the desired record set (passing the filter as an argument).

Note : A view can call a store procedure by using openquery or openrowset commands.

Comment: Yes, my primary suspect was the view getting resolved to a subquery, however based on Microsoft's [example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190237(v=sql.105).aspx), I would say it just expands the view inline: `SELECT Field FROM MyTable...`.